# Java J-unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, interface

I am testing a class that was implemented from an interface.
In my test class, I have created objects (Humains) that have a name and bank account value.

One of my methods to test takes an arrayList and compares with another list and if the person already exists, the amount will be added.

Code is something like that:
TEST CLASS

```
HumainImpl<Humain> humain = new HumainImpl<Humain>();
private Humain h1 = new Humain("AAA" , 2200);
private Humain h2 = new Humain("DDD" , 500);

@Test
public void testAddAmount(){
List<Humain> testing = new ArrayList<Humain>();
testing.add(h1);
testing.add(h2);

humain.placeList(testing);
}
```

the placeList(testing) method is in the HumainImpl class which calls another method in the Humain class that does the addition.
In the HumainImpl class there is also a list called implList.
Once this method placeList is called, the numbers for h1 and h2 in the test class are changing.
What I want, is that only the number for the implList to change.

Is it something normal that when adding up numbers or making changes while passing the h1 and h2 as parameter they will get effected ?

I have tried too many ways and I don't get it. I tried going through the list passed as a parameter copy the element in that list into another attribut and do the addition but it didn't help.

This works fine when I test another similar method that takes an element as a attribut, place(h1).

---

Test Class:

```
HumainImpl<Humain> humain = new HumainImpl<Humain>();
private Humain h1 = new Humain("AAA" , 2200);
private Humain h2 = new Humain("DDD" , 500);

@Test
public void testAddAmount(){
List<Humain> testing = new ArrayList<Humain>();
testing.add(h1);
testing.add(h2);

humain.placer(testing);  //placer(testing) is the method placer with a list parameter
}
```

HumainImpl:

```js
private boolean existe(T elt){
  boolean result = false;
  index = uneListe.indexOf(elt);
  
  if(index >= 0){
   result = true;
  }
  
  return result;
 }

@Override
 public boolean placer(T elt) {
  boolean result = false;
  boolean found = false;
  int i = -1;
  int nbExemple;
  
  if(elt != null){
   boolean existe = existe(elt);
   nbExemple = nbExemplaires(elt);
   
   if(uneListe.size() > 0 && existe){
    while(!found && i < uneListe.size()){
     i++;
     if(elt.equals(uneListe.get(i))){
      found = true;
     }
     
    }
    T element = uneListe.get(i);
    nbExemple = element.retournerNbExemplaires();
    elt.additionner(nbExemple);
    result = false;
  } else if(!existe && nbExemple >= 1 && 
     uneListe.size() < nbPlacesMaximum) {
     uneListe.add(elt);
     result = true; 
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 
@Override                                                    
 public void placer(List<T> liste) {
  iterateur(liste);
  
  while(liste != null && liste.size() > 0 && itList.hasNext()){
   placer(itList.next()); 
  }
 }
```

In the class Humain:

```js
@Override
 public void additionner(int nbExemplaires) {
  this.nbExemplaires += nbExemplaires;
 }

@Override
 public int retournerNbExemplaires() {
  return nbExemplaires;
 }
```

Comment: Without seeing all your code it is hard to say what is happening exactly.  But it sounds like you want to make a _copy_ of your `List`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the code.